# LinkedIn API 403 - “Access to posting shares denied”

Tags: php, laravel, linkedin-api

```
    $linkedIn = new \Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn('myconsumerkey', 'myconsumersecret');
    $linkedIn->setAccessToken('myaccesstoken');
    $options = array('json'=>
        array(
            'comment' => 'Hello World!',
            'visibility' => array(
                'code' => 'anyone'
            )
        )
    );

    $result = $linkedIn->post('v1/people/~/shares', $options);

    dd($result);
```

I don't understand why getting this error "Access to posting shares denied" anyone can help me?

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help should include the desired, expected and current behaviour - please see how to create an [mcve]

Comment: You need to use `w_share` flag while authentication.

Comment: thank you for your response but in my application checkbox of w_share is always checked